# elasticsearch 7x as gitlab service doesn't allow dot in variable name

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run elasticsearch 7.0.1 in my gitlab pipeline, here is configuration snippet:

```
test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
      alias: elastic
  variables:
    cluster.initial_master_nodes: elastic
    node.name: elastic
```

But when I run it I get following error message:

```
/bin/bash: line 82: export: `cluster.initial_master_nodes=elastic': not a valid identifier
```

It seems that Gitlab uses bash to export variables but bash doesn't allow dots in names. I tried escaping with double underscore but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names with a dot are not valid in sh and bash indeed.

The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods) has a solution (works from version 7.15):

```
Change the setting name to uppercase
Prefix it with ES_SETTING_
Escape any underscores (_) by duplicating them
Convert all periods (.) to underscores (_)
```

Try variable names (pay attention to double underscores):

```
ES_SETTING_CLUSTER_INITIAL__MASTER__NODES: elastic
ES_SETTING_NODE_NAME: elastic
```

Comment: you missed escaping underscores with double underscores (i edited it in the answer). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had this issue on bitbucket and changing the variable name as you pointed out works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "command", and pass it with the suffix: "-E{variable}"
An example follows.

```
services:
   - name: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.3"
     alias: "elasticsearch"
     command: [ "bin/elasticsearch",
       "-Expack.security.enabled=false",
       "-Ediscovery.type=single-node",
       "-Ehttp.cors.enabled=true",
       '-Expack.ml.enabled=false']
```